# Unexpected behaviour while clicking a button contained in a custom LinearLayout

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

I have a problem with a custom LinearLayout I'm creating for an application. Basically, the LinearLayout contain items, each item is a horizontal LinearLayout which contains a TextView and a Button. The LinearLayout is populated correctly, however, when I press the button (which has a background a custom background: selector) unexpected behaviour is happening. What's happening is that the button changes is appearance only on the last element of the LinearLayout, which doesn't make any sense.

The code that populates the LinearLayout is as follows:

```
View template = null;

    if (items.size() > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

            template = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.views_custom_list_item, null);
            template.setBackgroundDrawable(getProperBackgroundDrawable(i, items.size() - 1));

            TextView text = (TextView)template.findViewById(R.id.custom_list_text);
            text.setText(items.get(i));

            Button button = (Button)template.findViewById(R.id.custom_list_button);
            button.setId(i);
            button.setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundButton);

            button.setOnClickListener(callListener);

            addView(template);
            template = null;
        }

    }
```

I'm inflating an XML which contains the layout for each item, and then I set the properties accordingly. All that code is contained in a custom class which inherits from LinearLayout. Do you know where the problem is? thanks

This is my view,

[image]

And it doesn't matter what item I presse I get this,

[image]

This is the item XML:

`

```
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/custom_list_text"
    android:textSize="15sp" 
    android:textColor="@color/black" 
    android:paddingLeft="5dip" android:paddingRight="5dip" 
    android:layout_weight="1" 
    android:gravity="left" />

<ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/custom_list_button"/>
```

`

The XML on the main layout:

`<com.example.views.CustomLayoutView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/custom_phone_directory"
                android:layout_margin="5dip"
                xx:background_single="@drawable/button_complete" 
                xx:background_top="@drawable/button_top"
                xx:background_middle="@drawable/button_middle"
                xx:background_bottom="@drawable/button_bottom"
                xx:button_background="@drawable/button_phone_selector" />
</LinearLayout>`

Comment: You are setting Button ids inside your for -loop. Use setTag instead if you need to identify them within your OnClick observer.

Comment: Hi harism, yes I seted the Id within the for loop just to see if that changed the behaviour I'm getting (unsuccessful anyway), but yes I could use setTag to identify the items; however, the biggest problem is what I'm asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was that I can't reuse a drawable object within the list. I need to create a drawable for each of the buttons, that solves the problem. Thanks to raukodraug for all his support, and to the others who point me some issues.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try defining `template` inside the loop?

```
if (items.size() > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {

            View template = inflate(getContext(), R.layout.views_custom_list_item, null);
            template.setBackgroundDrawable(getProperBackgroundDrawable(i, items.size() - 1));

            TextView text = (TextView)template.findViewById(R.id.custom_list_text);
            text.setText(items.get(i));

            Button button = (Button)template.findViewById(R.id.custom_list_button);
            button.setId(i);
            button.setBackgroundDrawable(backgroundButton);

            button.setOnClickListener(callListener);

            addView(template);
        }

    }
```

I hope this helps

**EDIT**

Try using this for your selector, and also try adding it in the XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Non focused state -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_phone"" />
    <!-- Focused state -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
          android:state_pressed="false" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_phone_over" />   
    <!-- Pressed state -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_phone_over" />
 </selector>
```

I have a feeling that the problem is that you are reusing the drawable in the code, so if you are not doing it in the XML then create a new drawable for each background, instead of reusing the one.

Comment: Doesn't work either, I'm thinking the answer is in the item XML; both TextView and Button have an ID, because I'm adding this items in the LinearLayout is like the ID I'm setting is not enough to differentiate the items, resulting in the behaviour somewhat I'm getting: the last item, the button works with the selector

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the `XML`, can you paste it just to check it? you say the problem is in the background, not in the `clicklistener` right? because if it was in the `clicklistener`, maybe how you are differentiating the `buttons` is the key.

Comment: yes, the problem is in the background, the background is a selector (normal state, hover state); this background is applied to the button contained in each item. When I click the button, the onClick shows me that the right item have been pressed; however, the background changes for the button of the last item. If I play a little bit with the screen, suddenly it can change the background for all buttons

Comment: I wonder if its the way you are extending `LinearLayout`, is it `selectable/clickable/focusable`? are you using `android:duplicateParentState=true` in it and/or the `button` inside it?

Comment: the LinearLayout I'm extending is not selectable/clickable/focusable, the only thing that should be clickable is the button contained within the row items. If I set android:duplicateParentState=true on the button then nothing changes when I press the button, neither on the last item as it was doing already

Comment: The weird thing is that the click event is associated with the right button, how is your selector defined? why don't you add it in the XML code? Because of the click event being right, I think the problem is the drawable itself. Try it also with the default background.

Comment: this is the selector, `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_focused="true" 
  android:state_pressed="false" 
  android:drawable="@drawable/button_phone_over" />
 <item android:state_focused="true" 
  android:state_pressed="true" 
  android:drawable="@drawable/button_phone_over"/>
 <item android:state_focused="false" 
  android:state_pressed="true" 
  android:drawable="@drawable/button_phone_over"/>
 <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_phone"/>
</selector>`

Comment: the thing that's now interesting, is that I removed the setId on the button, and now on the onClick I get the same ID for whichever button I press, though this could to represent it doesn't have an id

Comment: I think the selector is ok because is working on the last item

Comment: yeah that behavior is not strange and expected, so in order to identify them you should use `setId` or `setTag`. So what happens if you don't set a background to the button? does the same thing happen?

Comment: If I remove the background of the Button, then everything behaves as expected. Any ideas? the selector is right, so is it a bug or something? I tried mutating the drawable background element, but I get the same results

Comment: I edited my answer with a suggestion, I hope that solves the problem

Comment: lol, hate this types of problems. I tried using the selector, but now it behaves similarly, when I press a button, all the buttons are selected or not, it depends, the only accurate is the button of the last item

Comment: lol, this is fun, i edited again my answer with a new selector, it feels like the buttons are getting into the focused state (hard to tell since the background is the same for focus and press).

Comment: on another note, are you adding the background in the xml instead of in the code?

Comment: I have a feeling that the problem is that you are reusing the drawable in the code, so if you are not doing it in the XML then create a new drawable for each background, instead of reusing the one.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I thought that it didn't matter to have this drawable store an reuse it. But yes, the solution was to get a new drawable for each button instead of reusing it. Solved. Thanks mate.

Comment: Nice! im glad it helped! Id suggest you mark it as solved so people know what to do if they face this problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a bug or a feature but similar behavior can be achieved with following code;

```
    Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    button2.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Here button2 is drawn as 'pressed' despite clicking button1 and it seems to relate to fact same drawable is assigned as a background for both buttons. You can get around this by creating own background Drawable for each button.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I thought that it didn't matter to have this drawable store an reuse it. But yes, the solution was to get a new drawable for each button instead of reusing it. Solved. Thanks mate.